# Haskell vs JVM performance

Tags: java, scala, haskell, jvm

I want to write a backend system for a web site (it'll be a custom search-style service). It needs to be highly concurrent and fast. Given my wish for concurrency, I was planning on using a functional language such as Haskell or Scala.

However, speed is also a priority. http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org results appear to show that Java is almost as fast as C/C++, Scala is generally pretty good, but Haskell ranges from slower to a lot slower for most tasks.

Does anyone have any performance benchmarks/experience of using Haskell vs Scala vs Java for performing highly concurrent tasks?

Some sites I've seen suggest that Scala has memory leaks which could be terrible for long running services such as this one.

What should I write my service in, or what should I take into account before choosing (performance and concurrency being the highest priorities)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume your problems are anything like the problems those benchmarks solve? And do you have any reason to assume you'll actually get to optimize your code as much as these benchmarks have been optimized (that is, a whole freaking lot)? If not, these benchmarks are worthless for your purposes. Also note that the Haskell benchmarks may be 10x slower than Java ones in the worst case, but the gap is much smaller for most Scala benchmarks.

Comment: If you evaluate Haskell, then please use GHC v7 which <a href="http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/smoking-fast-haskell-code-using-ghcs-new-llvm-codegen/">generates far faster code</a> using the LLVM. There should be a huge performance jump in Haskell vs. whatever evaluations due to the LLVM. Be warned, there are currently still distributions offering only GHC v6, notably MacPorts for Mac OS X.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking this question. Benchmark games are all well and good, but I'm interested in real-world application and performance.

Comment: Don't worry about memory leaks with Scala. It used to be a problem with the built-in actors implementation, but I believe that issue is now resolved, and [Akka](http://typesafe.com/technology/akka) is becoming the preferred library for actors, anyway.

Comment: @Jeff Burdges - the benchmarks game measurements were made using "The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.2.2"

Comment: @igouy: Yes, but they were as far as I can see not using the LLVM code generator, which has to be explicitly enabled with the `-fllvm` option.

Comment: @delnan - "And do you have any reason to assume you'll actually get to optimize your code as much as these benchmarks have been optimized (that is, a whole freaking lot)?" aka Can you write Haskell as-good-as Don Stewart ;-)

Comment: @hammar - Haskell programs designed for -fllvm have not been contributed yet.

Comment: @hammar I'm a total newb for Haskell, but I do Scala. And making Haskell fast is extremely difficult. Making Scala fast is just to be imperative at the right spot (which most people are able to program).

Comment: TBH it sounds to me like all you need is a super-fast database for the gazillions of concurrent queries your brand new website will certainly be getting. ;) Are you rolling your own DB? Are you writing the indexer as well?

Comment: <pendantic>Haskell is a language. Therefore the notion of speed is out of context (no less than measuring how well a fishbowl can form sentences). That said, you can measure an *implementation* of a language.</pendantic>

Comment: @trinithis <charitable>As user1037541 explicitly references measurements made with specific language implementations "the notion of speed" is in context.</charitable> Your pedantry is out of context :-) [The language names are simply shorthand for well-known language implementations.]

Comment: I didnt follow his link. I saw no reference to a Haskell implementation, such as GHC directly in the SO post. As for shorthand, GHC is shorter than Haskell ;D

Comment: @trinithis - user103754 cannot force you to follow the reference he provided and understand his meaning, you can always choose to misunderstand. LOL as-for-shorthand isn't Haskell shorter than Glasgow Haskell Compiler?

Comment: The GHC entries haven't been updated for quite a while -- pragmas were corrected to get ghc 7+ to compile them, but no one has tried to to take account of the peculiarities or advantages of ghc 7+. Everyone is impeded from experimentation by lack of quad cores - I. Gouy does not see that these completely changed the character of the competition, restricting it to a tiny class of users. No one can submit emended entries without testing ... In principle it should be advantageous to GHC, see e.g. threadring on quadcore which was turned into a winner by ghc 7 without being altered.

Comment: @applicative - "but no one has tried to to take account of the peculiarities or advantages of ghc 7+" TRUE. "Everyone is impeded from experimentation by lack of quad cores" JOKE! Please explain why Haskell programmers are more impeded by lack of quad cores than say Java programmers.

Comment: @applicative - "see e.g. threadring on quadcore which was turned into a winner by ghc 7 without being altered" - The thread-ring task does not benefit from 4-core. The thread-ring task is sequential.

Comment: Thread-ring is not improved by a division of work across cores; the reasons are pretty obvious and familiar to anyone who has worked on it. Its improved standing was due to the change in compiler version, which shows that the compiler has changed non-trivially and in principle for the better. -- In that case even complete passivity of the community could lead to improvement; it is the other cases that no one I know can test.  This is not a speculation.

Comment: @applicative - Please explain why Haskell programmers are more impeded by lack of quad cores than say Java programmers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This question is superficially about performance of code compiled with GHC vs code running on the JVM. But there are a lot of other factors that come into play.

**People**

- Is there a team working on this, or just you?

  - How familiar/comfortable is that team with these languages?
  - Is this a language you (all) want to invest time in learning?
- Who will maintain it?

**Behavior**

- How long is this project expected to live?
- When, if ever, is downtime acceptable?
- What kind of processing will this program do?

  - Are there well-known libraries that can aid you in this?
  - Are you willing to roll your own library? How difficult would this be in that language?

**Community**

- How much do you plan to draw from open source?
- How much do you plan to contribute to open source?
- How lively and helpful is the community

  - on StackOverflow
  - on irc
  - on Reddit
  - working on open source components that you might make use of

**Tools**

- Do you need an IDE?
- Do you need code profiling?
- What kind of testing do you want to do?
- How helpful is the language's documentation? And for the libraries you will use?
- Are there tools to fill needs you didn't even know you had yet?

There are a million and one other factors that you should consider. Whether you choose Scala, Java, or Haskell, I can almost guarantee that you will be able to meet your performance requirements (meaning, it probably requires approximately the same amount of intelligence to meet your performance requirements in any of those languages). The Haskell community is notoriously helpful, and my limited experience with the Scala community has been much the same as with Haskell. Personally I am starting to find Java rather icky compared to languages that at least have first-class functions. Also, there are a lot more Java programmers out there, causing a proliferation of information on the internet about Java, for better (more likely what you need to know is out there) or worse (lots of noise to sift through).

**tl;dr** I'm pretty sure performance is roughly the same. Consider other criteria.

Comment: "The Haskell community is notoriously helpful, and my limited experience with the Scala community has been much the same as with Haskell." - I don't know the Haskell community at all, but my experience with the Scala community has been terrible. Did you leave an "un" off of the "helpful" or have you found a non-chippy subset of the Scala community? If so, can you point me at them - I could use some help with my Scala coding.

Comment: @kittylyst: asking questions on both #scala irc and the scala tag at StackOverflow have been a great help to me. Sometimes caution is needed in order to produce a good experience. For example, I carefully worded [my latest Scala question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250109/generalizing-scala-code-into-a-function) to avoid sounding confrontational. Also, sometimes when asking questions, you have to be open to the possibility that you're simply not thinking in "the Scala way"; try not to take it offensively if/when people tell you that.

Answer (score 10):

You should pick the language that you know the best and which has the best library support for what you are trying to accomplish (note that Scala can use Java libraries).  Haskell is very likely adequate for your needs, if you learn enough to use it efficiently, and the same for Scala.  If you don't know the language reasonably well, it can be hard to write high-performance code.

My observation has been that one can write moderately faster *and* more compact high-performance parallel code in Scala than in Haskell.  You can't just use whatever most obviously comes to mind in either language, however, and expect it to be blazing fast.

Scala doesn't have actor-related memory leaks any more *except* if you use the default actors in a case where either you're CPU-limited so messages get created faster than they're consumed, or you forget to process all your messages.  This is a design choice rather than a bug, but can be the wrong design choice for certain types of fault-tolerant applications.  Akka overcomes these problems by using a different implementation of actors.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the head-to-head comparison. For some problems ghc and java7-server are very close. For equally many, there's a 2x difference, and for only one there's a 5x difference. That problem is k-nucleotide for which the GHC version uses a hand-rolled mutable hashtable since there isn't a good one in the stdlibs. I'd be willing to bet that some of the new datastructures work provides better hashtables than that one now.

In any case, if your problem is more like the first set of problems (pure computation) then there's not a big performance difference and if its more like the second (typically making essential use of mutation) then even with mutation you'll probably notice somewhat of a performance difference.

But again, it really depends on what you're doing. If you're searching over a large data set, you'll tend to be IO bound. If you're optimizing traversal of an immutable structure, haskell will be fine. If you're mutating a complex structure, then you may (depending) pay somewhat more.

Additionally, GHC's lightweight green threads can make certain types of server applications extremely efficient. So if the serving/switching itself would tend to be a bottleneck, then GHC may have the leg up.

Speed is well and good to care about, but the real difference is between using any compiled language and any scripting language. Beyond that, only in certain HPC situations are the sorts of differences we're talking about *really* going to matter.

Comment: "but the real difference is between using any compiled language and any scripting language" - Except if "you'll tend to be IO bound"?

Comment: @igouy: heh, point granted. but even then, the widefinder 2 results were dominated by compiled languages: http://wikis.sun.com/display/WideFinder/Results

Answer (score 4):

The shootout benchmark assumes the same algorithm is used in all implementations.  This gives the most advantage to C/C++ (which is the reference implementation in most cases) and languages like it.  If you were to use a different approach which suited a different language, this is disqualified.

If you start with a problem which more naturally described in Haskell it will perform best in that language (or one very much like it)

Often when people talk about using concurrency they forget the reason they are doing it is to make the application faster.  There are plenty of examples where using multiple threads is not much faster or much much slower.  I would start with an efficient single threaded implementation, as profiled/tuned as you can make it and then consider what could be performed concurrently. If its not faster this more than one CPU, don't make it concurrent.

IMHO: Performance is your highest priority (behind correctness), concurrency is only a priority in homework exercise.

Comment: Not true - C/C++ is not "the reference implementation". For example, the pi-digits task was taken from a Haskell program, the thread-ring task was taken from an Erlang program, fannkuch was taken from a Lisp program, binary-trees and n-body were taken from a Java programs, ... I don't program C/C++ which flat-out stops me from using C/C++ for reference implementations.

Comment: As a matter of fact, my practice was to test out the suitability of a task by writing programs in Clean, C# and PHP.

Comment: Lawrey is alluding to sentences like this: "Each program must implement 4 separate functions / procedures / methods like [the C# program](link)." In general entries are rejected for not following such instructions. (It might be wondered, by the way, on what principle the Scala entries are being accepted or rejected, looking at them now :) .)

Comment: @applicative - Please show where Peter Lawrey actually said that, or some other reason we should believe you have intimate knowledge of his thoughts. Meanwhile make specific complaints about a specific Scala programs so they can be checked - not vague innuendo.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have any performance benchmarks/experience of using
>   Haskell vs Scala vs Java for performing highly concurrent tasks?

Your specific solution architecture matters - [it matters a lot](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would say Scala, but then I have been experimenting with Scala so my preference would definitely be Scala. Any how, I have seen quite a few high performance multi-threaded applications written in Java, so I am not sure why this nature of an application would mandate going for FP. I would suggest you write a very small module based on what your application would need in both scala and haskell and measure the performance on your set up. And, may I also add clojure to the mix ? :-) I suspect you may want to stay with java, unless you are looking at benefiting from any other feature of the language you choose.