# Generalizing scala code into a function

Tags: function, generics, scala, haskell, types

So I accidentally wrote a Haskell answer to a Scala question recently. Being rather familiar with Haskell, the solution came quite easily to me:

```
myMaxBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
myMaxBy _ [] = undefined
myMaxBy f (x:xs) = foldr step [x] xs
  where step y acc@(z:_) = case f y z of
          GT -> [y]
          EQ -> y:acc
          LT -> acc
```

Then someone reminded me that it was a Scala question. I set out to transate my code into Scala, and after much pain I settled for:

```
(List(xs.head) /: xs.tail) { (acc, y) =>
  y compare acc.head match {
    1  => List(y)
    0  => y :: acc
    -1 => acc
  }
}
```

But I could not for the life of me get the Scala type system to bend to my will and generalize this into a function where `xs` and `compare` are inputs (ideally, curried inputs with the comparator first). Though this is surely due to my general unfamiliarity with Scala, I also slightly blame Scala's complex (though very powerful) type system. Can you do some hand-holding and walk me through how I could turn this into a *generalized* function, with a type signature similar to the Haskell equivalent? (Read: *as general as*.) Please also demonstrate usage, if it is more complicated than `myMaxBy(myCompare)(someList)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You missed out the `case` keywords in your pattern-match, which are quite important!

All you need is for the collection parameter type to be able to use a `compare` method. There are two systems for comparing things in Scala: extending `Ordered`, or using an `Ordering`. There are implicit conversions between the two so it doesn't matter too much which you choose; the first is perhaps easier to understand.

First off, using `Ordered`:

```
  def myMaxBy[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: List[A]) = {
    (List(xs.head) /: xs.tail) { (acc, y) =>
      y compare acc.head match {
        case 1  => List(y)
        case 0  => y :: acc
        case -1 => acc
      }
    }  
  }
```

Here we give our generic type `A` a *view bound* using `<%`, which means "can be seen as". This is more general than using an upper bound `<:`, and useful for classes that are not themselves `Ordered`, but have implicit conversions to `Ordered` classes, e.g. `Int` to `RichInt`.

Alternatively, if you want flexibility to be able to change the ordering criteria, you can write it like this:

```
  def myMaxBy[A](xs: List[A])(implicit ord: Ordering[A]) = {
    (List(xs.head) /: xs.tail) { (acc, y) =>
      ord.compare(y, acc.head) match {
        case 1  => List(y)
        case 0  => y :: acc
        case -1 => acc
      }
    }
  }
```

When invoking, if there's an implicit `Ordering[A]` in scope, you can leave the second argument out. This second way also has the advantage that you can define an `Ordering` on arbitrary classes, whether or not they already support it.

You can invoke both using, for example, `myMaxBy(List(1,2,3,4,3,4))`. In the second, if you wanted, say, reverse ordering:  `myMaxBy(List(1,2,3,4,3,4))(Ordering.Int.reverse)`.

Another thing you might see in this context are *context bounds*. E.g. `[A: Ordering]`. This means the same as `[A](implicit ord: Ordering[A])`, which is more concise, except that you don't get a handle on the `Ordering` so have to summon it using `implicitly`. So here it's probably best to state it explicity as above.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about `case`, I fixed my other answer accordingly! I tested it with `case` in my code but somehow omitted it when copying my code over.

Comment: You can put `import Ordering.Implicits._` at the top of the file, and thus avoid the `implicitly` summons all over the place.

Comment: @missingfaktor I'm not sure how that import would help, since the `Ordering.Ops` that we get does not have a `compare` method

Comment: I don't see a good reason to use pattern matching here. (and thus not for `compare` either.) Hence the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either have the A type extend Ordered or better, restrict it so there is an Ordering type class available. The first looks like:

```
def sort[A <: Ordered[A]](xs: List[A]) =
  (List(xs.head) /: xs.tail) { (acc, y) => y compare acc.head match { … } }
```

As Luigi points outeven better is to use the view bound <% rather than the subtype bound <: as it allows for types that have implicit conversions to Ordered views.

```
def sort[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: List[A]) =
  (List(xs.head) /: xs.tail) { (acc, y) => y compare acc.head match { … } }
```

Better though is to use the Ordering type class:

```
def sort[A](xs: List[A])(implicit ord: Ordering[A]) =
  (List(xs.head) /: xs.tail) { (acc, y) => ord compare (y, acc.head) match { … } }
```

You can use a context bound as well:

```
def sort[A: Ordering](xs: List[A]) = {
  val ord = implicitly[Ordering[A]]
  (List(xs.head) /: xs.tail) { (acc, y) => ord compare (y, acc.head) match { … } }
}
```

while this is slightly cleaner syntactically it doesn't let you pass in an explicit alternate Ordering (say case-insenitive ordering of Strings for instance).